# The Curvy Rebound: One of the most interesting (Geometric) Probability problems.

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry, dynamical-systems, geometric-probability

An infinitely small ball is placed at a random point on the red line shown on the right. The line is 10 metres long. The semi-circle that stems from this line is its resulting size too. Also positioned 3 metres above the centre of the line is a small circle with a diameter of 1 metre. There is no gravity of any sort by the way.

[image]

The ball is shot up into the semi-circle at a random angle from -90 degrees to +90 degrees. After it comes back past the red line, it is all over.

---

**Question-Part 1**: *What's the chance the 'ball' will contact the yellow circle?*

**Question-Part 2**: *Same question as above, except that the curve (which has now extended to become a full circle) rotates (pivot = point at centre of yellow circle) 45 degrees for every 5 metres the ball has travelled.*

---

**Background**: This question is from the same site (http://www.skytopia.com/project/imath/imath.html) I asked this question on MSE from: [Probability of the Center of a Square Being Contained in A Triangle With Vertices on its Boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167658/probability-of-the-center-of-a-square-being-contained-in-a-triangle-with-vertice)

**My effort**: This problem has vexed me a lot, and that too the first part itself. The second part looks seriously tough. So I'll just tell you the my effort for part 1.

I initially wanted to solve a very simple case, so I took one endpoint of the diameter. I could see that distance from the endpoint to the centre of the yellow circle would be $\sqrt{34}cm$  cm; therefore length of tangents to the circle from the endpoint would be $\sqrt{33.75}cm$ each. I then get ~ 9.84 degrees as the angle subtended by the chord joining the two points of contact (a.k.a. points where tangents from the endpoint touch the yellow circle) on the yellow circle at the endpoint.
      [image]

So I've evaluated that, for certain, the favourable event here, at one endpoint of the diameter, is at least 9.84 degrees out of a sample space of 180 degrees. But now, I have to evaluate:-

1. Other possibilities of angle which result in the ball to hit the yellow circle when initially at the end point. I hope I;ve been doing the right calculations so far.
2. Since this was just a grossly simplified case, it still doesn't get me close to the answer required for JUST PART ONE, as it (the ball) can lie anywhere on the red line (A.k.a. diameter of the big circle).
3. Part two. I'm pretty sure that this is far above my capability for now.

   ---

Sorry for the post being quite long; I'm sure the question is interesting enough. So essentially, to recap, my questions are:-

**Question(s): What is the solution to PART 1 and PART 2 of the question? How exactly can one approach this question and be successful in it? Has my approach been alright so far?**

---

Note:

To clarify:-

1. The balls bounces off, without loss of velocity. (There's no GRAVITY as previously stated in the question).
2. The curve which becomes the circle is the semi-circle, and this new circle pivots around the point which happens to be the centre of the yellow circle.
3. The red line rotates along with the circle, and this rotation is constantly clockwise.
4. For a few further details, read the comments.

Comment: Downvoter please explain. There is absolutely no reason for anyone to downvote this question.

Comment: I downvoted, and I will explain. This question is poorly phrased. What happens when the ball hits the blue semicircle? You haven't told us how or even whether the ball bounces ...

Comment: Also, the second part of the question is extremely unclear. Which curve is rotating? Which curve has become a full circle? The site from which you got this problem looks ridiculous. If you simply want to find difficult math problems/puzzles, I suggest you look [here](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c13_contests). The Putnam contest, for example, has notoriously difficult questions.

Comment: Obviously the semi-circle has become a circle, and that circle pivots around the point; there is not much ambiguity here . And of course the problems are ridiculous; hence they're fun to do. And I guess thank you for that link? I already have it in my bookmarks though...

Comment: Also @ZubinMukerjee I've added a note regarding the clarifications. TBH I really think those facts are not that ambiguous; still, I've made a change as you suggested to prevent ambiguity. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Still unclear. What happens to the red line when the circle pivots? Does it just stay where it was?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Specified sir. Thank you for having given these suggestions to make the question clearer.

Comment: Given those rules, the ball can end up *outside* the circle ... I don't think I want to spend more time on this, sorry.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee One has to assume that all shapes involved are indestructible. And please do explain how it can end up outside the circle.

Comment: Start in the middle, get shot with an angle of $90-\epsilon$ degrees, reach the edge right as the circle pivots ... now what? This question is stupid. I don't want to be mean, but why exactly do you want to try this imprecise puzzle posed by "Mr. Know-it-all" on a site that looks like it was somebody's first HTML?

Comment: Some questions do have answers of the site, hence I thought they're worth answering. And by 90 degrees you mean along OB? If so, then as the ball starts from the center and reaches point B, as the whole circle and its contents pivot around the yellow circle's center(after 5m), the sharp pivoting moves all the contents of the circle while the ball is independent. Here, don't assume that the circle is a membrane of some sort the ball will tear through. Then, I guess you'll have to consider that moment akin to the ball passing by the red line.

Comment: Also, @ZubinMukerjee You're right about one thing; more ambiguity. When the ball moves along the red like the aforementioned case we've been discussing, do we consider it to be never ending for the first part of the question because it never passes by the red line, and only along it, while the semi circle remains static? Or do we consider the vice-versa of this case? So yes...some doubts linger around.. I'll try updating the question to add in factors and details as suggestions come by....

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee You're an 18 year old who's already a second year student in Yale? Seriously impressive, and quite humbling.... Do you have good suggestions for books from which I could learn Contour integration?

Comment: Well, I for my part find this question very interesting! But that really might be a matter of taste, and should not result in a downvote. By definition: `This question does not show any research effort; is unclear or not useful`, none of those apply here as far as I can tell. What is asked also seems to be pretty clear (at least by now). Personal taste should not be a reason for downvoting (except for meta questions of course).

Comment: @Levit This is why I was initially surprised at the amount of downvotes. But that's trivial; this site is for learning and not about reputation (In fact, I wish to accrue more and more Reputation so that I can give bounties. I;ve already given 5-6 I think...) So what are your ideas regarding this question?

Comment: Well first off, I am not a mathematician, I just like such puzzles; so my point of view might not be that relevant/professional. That said, I would start by looking separately at the (at most) 3 "kinds of angles" that hit the target. Meaning: As I understand it, there are at most 3 ranges of angles for any starting point (1 for direct hits, and 2 possible reflection areas). For example: When starting in the center there is only the possibility for a direct hit, and in the corners there is only *one* possible reflection range. Adding those up while respecting intersections would be my approach.

Comment: @Levit That's how I've thought about it so far (Also calculated the angle subtended  by the yellow circle as shown in working). I guess this is where we all are stuck...

Comment: Just like to say that as the author of this question (!), Kugelblitz's intuitive assumptions regarding the possible ambiguities have all been spot on. For example, the red line does indeed rotate too - being 'fixed' to the circle. Regarding the infinitesimal small ball travelling along the red line forever; well, mathematically, that would only cover 0% of all possible angles, so any possible answer won't need to take that into account.

Comment: @DanW Could you please e-mail me the solutions for the questions on the site? [ philomathbau5@gmail.com ]

Comment: @Kugelblitz: I would, except I really don't know them.