# Probability of a small square existing in a larger square without intersecting the larger square's diagonals

Tags: probability

**Extra data:**

1. The length of the larger squares side is 2 units and the smaller one is 0.5 units
2. The smaller square can have *any* orientation
3. The smaller square fully lies in the larger one.
4. The smaller square is to be chosen by selecting a random point in the larger square as it's center, rotating it by a random angle and checking if it lies in the larger square

**My attempts at a solution:**

I first treated this as a generic probability question and tried solving it graphically with diagrams for the extreme cases, and then using the fractions of areas to get the answer but then I realized that there were infinite cases where the squares were in the correct position and a larger(?) infinity where the smaller square intersected the diagonals.

If this were true, then the required probability tends to zero but this implies that the probability that the smaller square intersects the diagonals tends to one which is intuitively wrong.

I then tried solving parametrically, taking one random point in the large square, finding the corresponding possible points for the smaller square with respect to the first point and theta(Angle with the horizontal) then with the inequalities we get comparing these points with the line equations of the diagonals, we can get the probability by dividing the possible theta values by 360.

However, in this case, when the first point is selected close to the squares edge, we get some cases that don't even fit in the sample space with the necessary conditions.

Comment: Please write coherent text (from a computer).  Sentences like this are a *mess*!  "My attempts at a solution I first treated this as a generic probab question and tried solving it graphically with diagrams for the extreme cases and then using the fractions of areas to get the answer but then I realized that there were infinite cases where the squares were in the correct position and a larger(?) infinity where the smaller square intersected the diagonals."

Comment: How would you describe the distribution of the small squares?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'm really sorry about that wall of text. I've edited it to make it more readable

Comment: @A.G. they are totally random as long as they are in the large square

Comment: "They are totally random" is not descriptive enough.  The answer will depend on the distribution of the squares.  [This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301918/what-is-the-probability-that-a-circle-contained-in-a-circle-a-contains-the-cente?noredirect=1#comment6794603_3301918) had a lengthy discussion on this very topic which got moved to a chatroom [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96576/discussion-on-question-by-rtho8888-what-is-the-probability-that-a-circle-contain) by a moderator.

Comment: Long story short, you run into things like [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) where when different assumptions are made on the distribution of objects being considered, you can arrive at totally different final answers.  The exact distribution must be made explicitly clear before any attempt can be made, and any attempts at answering before this was clarified completely need to clarify what assumptions had been made about the distribution or else they are incomplete and ambiguous.

Comment: I have voted for reopening this question now that you have added an explanation about your attempts. Besides, what is your motivation for this issue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the closure wasn't in reference to lack of attempts, I cast the first vote and this occurred after the edit with the attempts explanation was added.  It was in reference to the fact that this is ambiguously worded and no clear definition of how the squares are chosen "randomly," an issue which has yet to be resolved.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm not really sure what you mean when you want how 'randomly' the squares are distributed. The answer provided by jvdhooft was satisfactory by the way

Comment: @Davis Did you read the link to Bertrand's paradox given above and see how "randomly" picking a chord of a circle in different ways gave different answers?  An example of how you could randomly pick a square inside of your other square here... pick a single point uniformly at random inside of the larger square.  Place a smaller square of appropriate size centered around that point.  Rotate the square at an angle chosen uniformly at random.  If the square remains entirely within the larger square, keep it, else discard it as invalid and try to generate another square.

Comment: @Davis for extreme example, here is another "random" way of selecting squares.  Place the square in the dead center of the larger square and rotate it at an angle chosen uniformly at random.  Here is another, pick a point from each edge of the larger square at random and draw a line between opposite points.  These lines will intersect somewhere.  Use this as your center of your smaller square.  So on, so forth...  Depending on which distribution used, different weights will be given to different squares, causing changes in overall probability.

Comment: When talking about choosing a natural number at random, we cannot do so uniformly as well.  We could pick a number at random by flipping a coin until we get tails and our number be the number of heads we got before that happened, or we could do it by playing the lottery until we win and the number we picked be the number of times we lost in a row until that happened.  Both are processes where we randomly pick a natural number, and every natural number is even possible to get., but they have very different results when asking questions like "*what is the probability we got a 2?*"  Same here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for clarifying. I never considered those possibilities. The case I had in mind was where you would select the center of the smaller square at random in the larger square, rotate by a random angle and check if it lies in the larger square. I actually knew about Bertrand's paradox but didn't realize how it fit in this question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot for those insightful comments! I feel like a whole new perspective about probability has opened up for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming sides of length $4$ and $1$ for the large and small square, respectively. Furthermore, I am assuming that the rotation angle $\alpha$ between both squares is uniformly distributed within $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and that the top (left) corner of the small square is uniformly distributed within the valid region of the larger square.

[image]

If the rotation angle of the smallest square equals $\alpha$, then the area of possible points for the top (left) point of this square equals:

$$(4 - \sin \alpha - \cos \alpha)^2$$

[image]

We now need to find the area of the possible points for the top (left) point of this square, for which the square lies completely within one of four regions delimited by the diagonals. Applying basic formulas, and multiplying by $4$, we find:

$$\frac{(4 - \sin \alpha - 3 \cos \alpha)^2}{4} \cdot 4 = (4 - \sin \alpha - 3 \cos \alpha)^2$$

To arrive at the requested probability, we simply have to consider the ratio of the integrals of the two:

$$\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (4 - \sin \alpha - 3 \cos \alpha)^2 d \alpha}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (4 - \sin \alpha - \cos \alpha)^2 d \alpha} \approx \frac{0.680}{5.852} \approx 0.1161$$

This corresponds to the probability found by simulation in [the answer given by Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3322869/437988).

Comment: [+1] Very astute and moreover with didactic illustrations !

Comment: I hadn't at all this approach in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much! Ingenious answer!

Comment: This needs to clarify what assumptions were made as to the distribution of the squares.  See my above comments about [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted a simulation approach. Here is a result :

[image]

The diagonals of the big square define 4 isosceles rectangular triangles. I single out one of them, the western one $W$ (squares that fall into it are colored green).
It suffices to consider the probability $p$ of small squares to fall into $W$, then the final probability will be $4p$.

Experimental results show that $p \approx 0.029$.

Slightly related : [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1167658/probability-of-the-center-of-a-square-being-contained-in-a-triangle-with-vertice?rq=1).

The Matlab program that has created the figure :

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
> set(gcf,'color','w');
> plot([2,0,2,0,2,2,0,0],[2,0,0,2,0,2,2,0],'b');%square+diagonals
> r=0;g=0; 
> for k=1:500;% 500=number of attempts ; less small squares are generated
>    z=2*(rand+i*rand);% centre of small square
>    a=2*pi*rand;% orientation angle
>    v=z+0.25*sqrt(2)*exp(i*a)*[1,i,-1,-i];%square's vertices
>    xv=real(v);yv=imag(v);
>    if all([xv>0,yv>0,xv<2,yv<2])
>        plot([v,v(1)],'r')
>        r=r+1;% accounts here for all squares, either red or green.
>    end;
>    if all([xv>0,yv>0,(xv+yv)<2,xv<yv])
>        plot([v,v(1)],'g')
>        g=g+1;
>    end;
> end
> p=g/r
> ```

Comment: I have confirmed your simulation results. Could you check if this corresponds to what you had in mind?

Comment: This was one of the questions that popped up in my math class to which none of us could find the answer to. We tried to make a simulation but that didn't go too well. Thank you for your help! Beautiful program, by the way

Comment: This needs to clarify what assumptions were made as to the distribution of the squares.  See my above comments about [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree with you. This is a reason why I supplied my code ; nevertheless, I should have said it explicitly : the centers of the small squares are uniformly distributed within the big square (with an elimination/thinning process for small squares having at least one of their vertices outside the big square ; inclination angle of the small squares is as well uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$.